# system-config-printer fails to launch

Tags: printing, python

12.04 system-config-printer fails to launch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 31, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import gobject as _gobject
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>

ImportError: No module named _glib
```

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but it would have helped to specify what version of system-config-printer you were running at the time.  You can see that by running `dpkg -l | grep system-config-printer`

Comment: My guess is you were running this under an older version of Python for which `system-config-printer` is not supported.